# Execution of a Play application deployed on heroku from Bamboo: Why Application Error?

Tags: heroku, playframework, bamboo, procfile

I deployed a Play application! from Bamboo on Heroku, the deployement is normally and I can find my application on my Heroku account.
the problem is that when I run my application: it gives me:

Application Error

An error occurred in the your page Could not be served and implementation. Please try again in a FEW times.

If you are under the owner, check your logs for details.

Besides, I've created a PROCFILE containing:

```
Web: play run-Xmx512M -% ​​prod - http port = $ PORT-Dprecompiled = true.
```

Then I added these lines to the configuration file of the Play application! (file application.conf)

```
# Application mode
# ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
# Set to dev to enable instant reloading and other development help.
# Otherwise set to prod.
application.mode = dev
prod.application.mode% = prod
```

Heroku the logs gives me:

```
app [web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.Life
cycleException: Failed to start component [standardservice [Tomcat]] heroku [web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I tried to run the command:

```
heroku run bash - app myApp
```

it gave me:

```
 Running `bash` attached to terminal ... up, run.2767
  ! Heroku customer internal error.
  ! Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
```

In addition, I do not understand why Heroku does not take into consideration my Procfile ? because Dynos contains:

**Dynos**

```
  Web PRE_JAVA} $ {JAVA_OPTS} $ {java-jar webapp-runner-7.0.34.3.jar - p ...
```

Could someone helps me ? what must I do ? any ideas ?

Comment: do you mean Cedar? Bamboo is Ruby only, Cedar is polyglot.

Comment: I use Bamboo as a continuous integration server. Bamboo will deploy my Play application on Heroku!

Comment: Ah my bad, Seems you are taking about atlassian banboo not the heroku stack that was named bamboo.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using atlassian bamboo for continuous integration! and heroku Cedar.